# Apache Beam on Google Cloud stuck/not running after update from 1.9.0 to 2.1.0

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

UPDATE: Solved: I had a dependency in my pom on

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

which itself referenced com.fasterxml.jackson packages, which was the root of the problem. Got this after adding dependencies step by step to an initial project. I now shaded these dependencies:

```
<relocations>
    <relocation>
        <pattern>com.google.protobuf</pattern>
        <shadedPattern>com.shaded_storage.google.protobuf</shadedPattern>
    </relocation>
    <relocation>
        <pattern>com.fasterxml</pattern>
        <shadedPattern>com.fasterxml.shaded</shadedPattern>
    </relocation>
    <relocation>
        <pattern>org.codehaus.jackson</pattern>
        <shadedPattern>org.codehaus.jackson.shaded</shadedPattern>
    </relocation>
</relocations>
```

and in my initial project it seems to work. Will test this now on the main project and hope this works.

Had to tweak a few more deps and now it seems to work. Hope this is still the case when the projects run on Google App Engine again.

---

Initial Question for stuck pipeline started but not really running:

Today I updated my Dataflow-Project from Googles Version 1.9.0 to Apache Beam 2.1.0. The Pipelines are running on Google Cloud.

As I messed up some data beforehand, I wanted to run a really small sample-Pipeline to clean this up, which would load 343 Rows from Google Datastore, transform the Entities to a Pojo and write them back to Google Datastore (By that the keys and an attribute called ID would be updated).

I started the Pipeline 20 minutes ago and it still did not load a single entity from datastore. Seems like it is stuck. I will kill the Job and start it a second time, but I would like to know what the problem is.

The JobId: 2017-09-19_10_08_32-9486491048477927168

Logs: [image]

The Pipeline:

[image]

The summary etc from console:

[image]

The code:

```
public static void main(String...args) {
    Pipeline pipe = PipelineCreation.getN1Standard1("updatekeys");
    pipe.apply("ReadArticles", DatastoreIO.v1().read().withNamespace("XXXXX").withProjectId(C.PROJECT_ID).withQuery(DatastoreUtil.getPropertyEqualsQuery("article", "catalogKey", "XXXX")))
        .apply("ToPojo", ParDo.of(new ArticleFromEntity()))
        .apply("ToEntity", ParDo.of(new ArticleToEntity("XXXXX", "article")))
        .apply(DatastoreIO.v1().write().withProjectId(C.PROJECT_ID));
    pipe.run();
}

public static Pipeline getN1Standard1(String jobName){
    DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
    options.setProject("bmt-katalogintegration");
    options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
    options.setStagingLocation("gs://katalog-df-staging/binaries"); 
    options.setTempLocation("gs://katalog-df-staging/binaries/tmp");
    options.setGcpTempLocation("gs://katalog-df-staging/binaries/tmp");
    options.setZone("europe-west3-a");
    options.setJobName(jobName);
    options.setMaxNumWorkers(6);
    options.setWorkerMachineType("n1-standard-1");
    return Pipeline.create(options);
}

public static Query getPropertyEqualsQuery(String kind, String property, String value){
    Query query = Query.newBuilder()
            .addKind(KindExpression.newBuilder().setName(kind).build())
            .setFilter(Filter.newBuilder()
                    .setPropertyFilter(PropertyFilter.newBuilder()
                            .setProperty(PropertyReference.newBuilder()
                                    .setName(property))
                            .setOp(PropertyFilter.Operator.EQUAL)
                            .setValue(Value.newBuilder().setStringValue(value).build())
                            .build())
                    .build())
            .build();
    return query;
}
```

Feedback would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: The second Job also doesn't work. JobId: 2017-09-19_10_46_05-8997694731596581186

EDIT: Errors from Stackdriver:

```
    E   at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.main(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:56) 
E   at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorkerHarnessHelper.initializeGlobalStateAndPipelineOptions(DataflowWorkerHarnessHelper.java:39) 
E   at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkerPipelineOptionsFactory.createFromSystemProperties(WorkerPipelineOptionsFactory.java:48) 
E   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2858) 
E   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3814) 
E   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:216) 
E   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1012) 
E  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information 
E   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:1456) 
E   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270) 
E   at [Source: {"display_data":[{"key":"jobName","namespace":"org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions","type":"STRING","value":"updatekeys4"},{"key":"tempLocation","namespace":"org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions","type":"STRING","value":"gs://katalog-df-staging/binaries/tmp"},{"key":"zone","namespace":"org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions","type":"STRING","value":"europe-west3-a"},{"key":"appName","namespace":"org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ApplicationNameOptions","type":"STRING","value":"PipelineCreation"},{"key":"stagingLocation","namespace":"org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions","type":"STRING","value":"gs://katalog-df-staging/binaries"},{"key":"zone","namespace":"org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions","type":"STRING","value":"europe-west3-a"},{"key":"maxNumWorkers","namespace":"org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions","type":"INTEGER","value":6},{"key":"project","namespace":"org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions","type":"STRING","value":"bmt-katalogintegration"},{"key":"workerMachineType","namespace":"org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions","type":"STRING","value":"n1-standard-1"},{"key":"runner","namespace":"org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions","shortValue":"DataflowRunner","type":"JAVA_CLASS","value":"org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner"},{"key":"gcpTempLocation","namespace":"org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions","type":"STRING","value":"gs://katalog-df-staging/binaries/tmp"}],"options":{"apiRootUrl":"https://dataflow.googleapis.com/","appName":"PipelineCreation","autoscalingAlgorithm":"NONE","credentialFactoryClass":"org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.auth.GcpCredentialFactory","dataflowEndpoint":"","dataflowJobId":"2017-09-20_04_31_04-12049147039561540392","enableCloudDebugger":false,"gcpTempLocation":"gs://katalog-df-staging/binaries/tmp","jobName":"updatekeys4","maxNumWorkers":6,"numWorkers":3,"numberOfWorkerHarnessThreads":0,"pathValidatorClass":"org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator","project":"bmt-katalogintegration","runner":"org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner","stableUniqueNames":"WARNING","stagerClass":"org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.GcsStager","stagingLocation":"gs://katalog-df-staging/binaries","streaming":false,"tempLocation":"gs://katalog-df-staging/binaries/tmp","workerMachineType":"n1-standard-1","zone":"europe-west3-a"}}; line: 1, column: 1] 
E  Uncaught exception in main thread. Exiting with status code 1. 
W  Please use a logger instead of System.out or System.err.
Please switch to using org.slf4j.Logger.
See: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/logging 
E  Uncaught exception in main thread. Exiting with status code 1.
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant code of PipelineCreation, or change your example to not use it? [the "minimal, complete and reproducible" standard https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ] It's possible that there is something wrong with your pipeline setup, e.g. perhaps workers don't start up at all. Do you see any errors in the Dataflow logs or in Stackdriver worker logs for the job?

Comment: Alright, thank you for the tip to look into stackdriver, there is an exception with com.fasterxml.jackson,
i.e: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

I will update the question again

Comment: The error seems to suggest a problem reading in the PipelineOptions. We've tried a simple repro based on the options you have here and don't see any problems. Are there any other PipelineOptions possibly involved? Are you passing any options from the command line?

Comment: No I do not. I guess this might be a dependency-problem. I have a shaded model-Project and a main-dataflow-project which itself uses storage-deps, the runner-deps and apache-gcp-io. I am building an initial project and will compare the dependency-trees. Will come back when I know more. Thank you for your testing!

Comment: So the initial-project with a simple TextIO to/from GStorage works fine, will compare them now :-)

Comment: I can confirm, the problem was the referenced dependency from google-storage, will update the question